# Apply Bootstrap style to only a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I wanna apply this style 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">` only to a div without affecting the entire website style, is it possible? Here is the div:

```
<div class="nav-scroller py-1 mb-2">

    <nav class="nav d-flex justify-content-between">

        <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Menu 3</a>

    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you include bootstrap if that need only at one block? Look what style apply now to this block(in devtools for example), copy it, add selector to this block. And after that => .thisBlock{ copied styles}

Comment: As the linked question shows, it is possible. But it's wrong. ***Seriously*** wrong. You're adding a total of 10382 lines of code (unpacked) when you only need about 15 of them.